# How do I get a list of posts made by a user with RedditSharp?

Tags: c#, reddit

I did:

```
Listing<Post> listing = reddit.User.GetPosts(Sort.New, 5, FromTime.Week);
```

But there's no enumerator for Listing. So I spent a ton of time looking into this and put this together:

```
Listing<Post> listing = reddit.User.GetPosts(Sort.New, 5, FromTime.Week);
listing.Stream(); //Had to call stream to get IsStream to be true

IAsyncEnumerator<Post> p = listing.GetEnumerator(5, 5, true);
p.MoveNext(); //MoveNext should populate Current object

var c = p.Current;
```

But the `Current` object is always null. And even if it worked, that's a single post. So I guess I'm just confused on how it all works because that's an incredibly convoluted way to grab a list of posts.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your p variable is an asynchronous enumerator, so the call to MoveNext needs to be awaited. You can then call MoveNext until it returns false, meaning it has enumerated over all posts in your enumerator.

```
var listing = reddit.User.GetPosts(Sort.New, 5, FromTime.Week);
var posts = listing.GetEnumerator(5, 5, true);

while (posts.MoveNext().Result)
{
    var post = posts.Current;
    // Do something with post...
}
```